# Unable to access Smartsheet SCIM APIs

Tags: smartsheet-api, scim, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have a Smartsheet enterprise account with system admin privileges. But, when I try to access the SCIM API(https://scim.smartsheet.com/v2/Users) getting the following error:

{
"schemas": [
"urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
],
"detail": "This feature is not enabled for your organization. Please contact your Customer Support Manager (CSM).",
"status": "403"
}

I couldn't find any option to enable SCIM in the Smartsheet platform. How to fix this issue?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a feature that Smartsheet must specifically enable for your account, before you're able to use it. You should do as the error message suggests and contact your Smartsheet account rep. If you don't know who your Smartsheet account rep is, I'd suggest [opening a ticket with the Support team](https://help.smartsheet.com/contact/smartsheetapp) to ask them to enable this feature for your account.

I'd think that these are the values you'd want to select for the dropdown lists:

[image]